# Concatenate consecutive rows in R using data table

Tags: r, data.table, concatenation

I have a dataset like this

```
X1         X2     X3  
Cat        123    11
9                                                                
Cat        456    22
8                                                                
Cat        789    33
7
```

Is there any way by which I can concatenate consecutive rows and form new data set like this

```
X1         X2     X3  
Cat9       123    11
Cat8       456    22
Cat7       789    33
```

Note - Even rows for x2 and x3 are intentionally blank

Comment: whats there on the even rows for x2 and x3? can you dput your df?

Comment: there is no data, it is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically odd rows and even rows data table are fetched and then concatenated to form the final desired output.

```
library(data.table)

#convert odd rows data table into matrix
DT1 <- as.matrix(DT[seq(1, nrow(DT), by = 2), ])
#convert even rows data table into matrix
DT2 <- as.matrix(DT[seq(2, nrow(DT), by = 2), ])

#final result
as.data.table(matrix(paste0(DT1, DT2), nrow = nrow(DT1)))
```

**Sample data:**

```
DT <- structure(list(X1 = c("Cat", "9", "Cat", "8", "Cat", "7"), X2 = c("123", "", "456", "", "789", ""), X3 = c("11", "", "22", "", "33", "")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a crude way of doing it probably. You can `cbind` the even and odd rows, and then use `paste0`:

```
dt2<-cbind(dt1[seq(1,(nrow(dt1)-1),2),],X4=dt1[seq(2,(nrow(dt1)),2),]$X1)
dt2<-dt2[,.(X1=paste0(X1,X4),X2,X3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Prem's sample data:

```
DTclean <- DT[1:nrow(DT) %% 2 != 0]
DTclean[, X1 := paste0(X1, DT[1:nrow(DT) %% 2 == 0, X1])]
DTclean
     X1  X2 X3
1: Cat9 123 11
2: Cat8 456 22
3: Cat7 789 33
```